# MYSQL request from two tables with FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, count, request

I have two tables (MySQL):

1. table_products: // cid (text) - comma separated categories list // id (int11)

   ```
   id   cid
   1    1,2,3        
   2    5,21,8
   3    2,4,15
   ```
2. table_categories

   ```
   id   name   parent        
   1    Cat1   0      
   2    Cat2   0
   3    Cat3   0
   4    Cat4   0
   ```

This is my request:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `parent`
FROM `table_categories`
ORDER BY `parent` ASC, `id` ASC;
```

How can I perform the request above and also get the number of products in each category (from table_products).
May be using (FIND_IN_SET).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If every category is present in `table_categories`, then you could use this:

```
SELECT table_categories.name, count(table_products.id)
FROM
  table_categories LEFT JOIN products
  ON FIND_IN_SET(table_categories.id, products.cid)
GROUP BY table_categories.name
```

If table_categories.id is present in products.cid then FIND_IN_SET will return a non-zero value, and the join will succeed.

Comment: Thanks. This request do not return empty categories...How to return empty categories. Thanks!

Comment: @user889349 i changed my query using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN, it should be okay now

Comment: I rewrite your query to SELECT C.id, C.name, C.parent, C.description, COUNT(*) AS products
FROM `categories` C LEFT JOIN `products` P ON FIND_IN_SET(C.id, P.cid) GROUP BY C.name ORDER BY C.ordering ASC, C.parent ASC, C.id ASC but everytime this return 1 even for empty categories...

Comment: @user889349 sorry i had to change also the count(), if the join doesn't succeed table_products.id will be null and won't be counted now

Comment: @fthiella How can I speed up the query response, as I have data in millions and it is taking 23 seconds to load data?